# Javascript\JQuery function does not work without an alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a problem with my 2 JQuery\Javascript functions. My problem is that when I dont have alerts in both my functions, both the functions don't work properly, and the event agument and eventtarget parameters are overwritten.

please advise on the solution for this.

```
 function SubmitAdded() {

      $(document).ready(function (){
      var arrAdded = new Array();
      $('#JQAddedList li').each(function (i) {
          arrAdded[i] = $(this).text();
      });

          __doPostBack("AddActivity", arrAdded);
         // alert('if this alert is commented out, function does not work.');

 });
  }
```

Comment: Why `document.ready` is inside another function ?? also second `});` are for what ??

Comment: How is SubmitAdded getting called?  It's a little odd to see the document.ready event inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

> // alert('Added ('if this alert is
>   commented out, function does not
>   work.');

You seem to have one parenthesis to many...

or as someone more intelligent than me said:

"It's not the parenthesis that there's one too many of, it's the excess quote. – Xhalent"

Comment: It's not the parenthesis that there's one too many of, it's the excess quote.

Comment: That's what I meant actually, glad some of us are awake :)

Answer (score 1):

I usually take situations like this to mean that there is a timing issue involved. The alert box causes the script to pause long enough for the the state to change. If the alert doesnt occur then the script speeds through too quickly and your page/script wasnt in the state you thought it would be in when it runs through.

I'm not sure without more details, but offhand your script looks wrong in that it is wiring up a document ready event inside another function. You should try refactoring it into two functions and see if that fixes it.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var arrAdded = new Array();
    $('#JQAddedList li').each(function (i) {
        arrAdded[i] = $(this).text();
    });
});

function SubmitAdded() {
    __doPostBack("AddActivity", arrAdded);
}
```